# Why isn't my multithreaded app doing what it should do?

Tags: c#, multithreading

I'm using the ThreadPool to manage my threads. Separately from the UI thread I have a thread that does data retrieval and general work operations and I have a 3rd thread that updates the UI to reflect the status of requested operations.

See code below:

```
// ui thread
private void btnLoadClients_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // start thread 1
    ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(new Form1().LoadClientList);
}

// thread 1
private void LoadClientList(object state)
{
    ThreadBusy = true;
    ThreadAction = "Loading Clients...";

    // start thread 2
    ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(new Form1().ShowProgress);

    // get data
    ClientController c = new ClientController();
    List<Client> clients = c.GetClient();

    foreach (Client item in clients)
    {
        cmbClientList.Items.Add(item.Name);
    }
    cmbClientList.Items.Insert(0, "Please select a client");

    ThreadBusy = false;
}

// thread 2
private void ShowProgress(object state)
{
    while (ThreadBusy)
    {
        foreach (string action in lstAction.Items)
        {
            // write the action that's being taken to the listbox
            if (String.Compare(action, ThreadAction) != 0)
                lstAction.Items.Add(ThreadAction);
        }                
    }
}
```

Problem is that although ShowProgress is being hit when I set a breakpoint on it, execution isn't entering it really. The `while (ThreadBusy)` line isn't getting hit ever.

Have I got anything wrong here?

Comment: Use `delegates` to update things from the UI thread from other threads.

Comment: Just use a BackgroundWorker.  It's specifically designed to do exactly this.  Alternatively use `Task` and `await`.

Comment: @Neijwiert He *is* using delegates, he's just not using the proper operations to marshal to the UI thread, nor is he doing the right things i this methods to do what he wants, even if they were running in the UI thread.

Answer (score 5):

```
ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(new Form1().LoadClientList);

ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(new Form1().ShowProgress);
```

You're creating new `Form1` instances every time you start a background thread, every action you take in these methods will happen to these new, "unbounded" instances, not on the one interacting with the user.

If you want to perform background work in WinForms you can leverage the [`BackgroundWorker`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker.aspx) class.

A really simple example:

```
public static class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        var backgroundWorker = new BackgroundWorker();

        backgroundWorker.WorkerReportsProgress = true

        backgroundWorker.Disposed += BackgroundWorker_Disposed;
        backgroundWorker.DoWork += BackgroundWorker_DoWork;
        backgroundWorker.ProgressChanged += BackgroundWorker_ProgressChanged;
        backgroundWorker.RunWorkerCompleted += BackgroundWorker_RunWorkerCompleted;

        backgroundWorker.RunWorkerAsync();
    }

    private static void BackgroundWorker_Disposed(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // Cleanup after yourself.
    }

    private static void BackgroundWorker_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
    {
        // Do your things in background.
    }

    private static void BackgroundWorker_ProgressChanged(object sender, ProgressChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        // Notify progress.
    }

    private static void BackgroundWorker_RunWorkerCompleted(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        // The background task is complete ("successfully" is NOT implied).
    }
}
```

Comment: While technically correct, this would be a better answer if it contained a fix, or some general advice on how to fix, the problem.

Comment: @BradleyUffner I totally agree with you, but I haven't used WinForms for a long time and I'm not able to suggest the best course of action by memory. I'm looking it up, but if anyone can provide and example in the meanwhile he's welcome.

Comment: I'd start with sending a reference to the existing form instead of sending a new instance.  Looking at the code, it seems this will now cause cross threading problems, since the threadpool thread will be touching UI.  The fix for that is proper use of `InvokeRequired` and `BeginInvoke`. `ShowProgress` should probably be throttled in some way too, so that doesn't strangle the UI thread with constant updates.

Comment: @BradleyUffner I'm more a `BackgroundWorker` fan (see updated answer), I think it's more user friendly than `Invoke`.

Comment: So what exactly is supposed to go into the _Disposed void? "Cleanup" is vague. I never write disposable classes because I don't know how this works

Comment: I think `BackgroundWorker` is a little outdated too. Personally I prefer `Task.Run(` with a [`IProgress<T>`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh138298(v=vs.110).aspx) parameter passed in to the method. If you do a [`new Progress<T>()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh193692(v=vs.110).aspx) on the UI thread doing [`IProgress.Report(whatever)`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh137797(v=vs.110).aspx) on the background thread does the UI marshaling.

Comment: @Ortund well, only you know what to place there. If you don't need to clean up anything (no disposal, no things to close, etc) don't subscribe that event and you're fine, it's not mandatory (I've added it for completeness).

Comment: @Ortund Go read "[IDisposable: What Your Mother Never Told You About Resource Deallocation](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/29534/IDisposable-What-Your-Mother-Never-Told-You-About)", a very good article written by [Stephen Cleary](http://stackoverflow.com/users/263693/stephen-cleary) that explains what dispose is, and what it is not, for.

Comment: @ScottChamberlain I think you should post your idea as an answer, it's interesting. By the way, why do you consider the `BackgroundWorker` outdated? Surely the `async`/`await` pattern (where you can use it) is better, followed by a `Task.Run` to offhand the computation to the TPL, but the `BackgroundWorker` has its merits too, especially when you're dealing with .NET < 4.5.

Comment: You don't have to use async/await with a Task.Run, you only need to use it if you want to observe a exception or be notified of the completion (basicly only in the situations where you would have wanted to subscribe to `RunWorkerCompleted`), if you don't care about the exception you don't need to observe it.  As for being outdated I think Task.Run is simpler, less events and configuration options you need to remember to set up (for example, your current code has a bug because you subscribed to `ProgressChanged` but forgot to do `backgroundWorker.WorkerReportsProgress = true`).

Comment: Yes, I expressed myself badly. I mean "the async/await pattern" and the "Task.Run pattern" as different entities, not to be used together. I listed them as three possible alternatives (I decoupled the async/await one from the Task.Run one because once you go async you "can't" go back, and you can't always afford do that).

Answer (score 0):

ThreadBusy property that you set to true belongs to a different Form1 object. because the thread that runs ShowProgress executes on a new instance of Form1 and its ThreadBusy property is false always. Thats why it is not entering into the while loop.

Can you try this

```
ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(this.ShowProgress);
```

instead of

```
ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(new Form1().ShowProgress);
```